# ParserError: Source file requires different compiler version

Tags: python, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, brownie

I tried all that you mentioned in the discussion here (in other questions) and at https://github.com/smartcontractkit/full-blockchain-solidity-course-py/discussions/522 , however it is not solving the issue for me, I also noticed that the current compiler version remains (current compiler is 0.6.12+commit.27d51765.Windows.msvc). But when I right click and select Solidty:Compiler information, it shows 0.8.0.

**from output:**

```
Retrieving compiler information:
Compiler using remote version: 'v0.8.0+commit.c7dfd78e', solidity version: 0.8.0+commit.c7dfd78e.Emscripten.clang
```

Not sure if that is related to the issue I face.  Anyways starting with the problem I see when running brownie compile. I get the error below:

**error in terminal:**

```
PS D:\Python projects\Solidity dev\demo\smartcontract-lottery> brownie compile
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Brownie v1.17.2 - Python development framework for Ethereum

Compiling contracts...
  Solc version: 0.6.12
  Optimizer: Enabled  Runs: 200
  EVM Version: Istanbul
CompilerError: solc returned the following errors:

C:/Users/rosne/.brownie/packages/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.3.0/contracts/access/Ownable.sol:3:1: ParserError: Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.6.12+commit.27d51765.Windows.msvc) - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
^---------------------^

C:/Users/rosne/.brownie/packages/smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@0.2.1/contracts/src/v0.8/VRFConsumerBase.sol:2:1: ParserError: Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.6.12+commit.27d51765.Windows.msvc) - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
^---------------------^

PS D:\Python projects\Solidity dev\demo\smartcontract-lottery>
```

**My .sol file is Lottery.sol:**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/VRFConsumerBase.sol";

contract Lottery is VRFConsumerBase, Ownable {
    uint256 usdEntryFee;
    address payable[] public players;
    address payable public recentWinner;
    uint256 public randomness;
    AggregatorV3Interface internal ethUsdPriceFeed;
    enum LOTTERY_STATE {
        OPEN,
        CLOSED,
        CALCULATING_WINNER
    }

    LOTTERY_STATE public lottery_state;
    uint256 public fee;
    bytes32 public keyhash;

    constructor(
        address _priceFeedAddress,
        address _vrfCoordinator,
        address _link,
        uint256 _fee,
        bytes32 _keyhash
    ) public VRFConsumerBase(_vrfCoordinator, _link) {
        usdEntryFee = 50 * (10**18);
        ethUsdPriceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(_priceFeedAddress);
        lottery_state = LOTTERY_STATE.CLOSED;
        fee = _fee;
        keyhash = _keyhash;
    }

    function enter() public payable {
        //$50 min
        require(lottery_state == LOTTERY_STATE.OPEN);
        require(msg.value >= getEntranceFee(), "Not enough ETH!");
        players.push(payable(msg.sender));
    }

    function getEntranceFee() public view returns (uint256) {
        (, int256 price, , , ) = ethUsdPriceFeed.latestRoundData();
        uint256 adjustedPrice = uint256(price) * 10**12; //18 decimals
        //$50, 2000 ETH
        //50/2000
        //50*10000/2000
        uint256 costToEnter = (usdEntryFee * 10**18) / adjustedPrice;
        return costToEnter;
    }

    function startLottery() public onlyOwner {
        require(
            lottery_state == LOTTERY_STATE.CLOSED,
            "cant start a new lottery yet"
        );
        lottery_state = LOTTERY_STATE.OPEN;
    }

    function endLottery() public onlyOwner {
        lottery_state = LOTTERY_STATE.CALCULATING_WINNER;
        bytes32 requestId = requestRandomness(keyhash, fee);
    }

    function FulfillRandomness(bytes32 _requestId, uint256 _randomness)
        internal
        override
    {
        require(
            lottery_state == LOTTERY_STATE.CALCULATING_WINNER,
            "you arent there yet!"
        );

        require(_randomness > 0, "random not found");
        uint256 indexOfWinner = _randomness % players.length;
        recentWinner = players[indexOfWinner];
        recentWinner.transfer(address(this).balance);

        //reset

        players = new address payable[](0);
        lottery_state = LOTTERY_STATE.CLOSED;
        randomness = _randomness;
    }
}
```

I also tried to google some solutions so my settings.json file is a bit different but that didnt help too.

**settings.json:**

```
{
    "solidity.compileUsingRemoteVersion": "v0.8.0+commit.c7dfd78e",
    "solidity.defaultCompiler": "remote",
    "solidity.compileUsingLocalVersion": "d:\\Python projects\\Solidity dev\\demo\\smartcontract-lottery\\soljson-v0.8.0+commit.c7dfd78e.js"
    // "solidity.compileUsingRemoteVersion": "v0.7.4+commit.3f05b770",
    // "solidity.enableLocalNodeCompiler": false
}
```

In the brownie-config.yaml, I tried all the versions of openzepplin contracts too from old to latest (4.4.0, 4.3.0,4.3.2 etc), but same error.

**brownie-config.yaml**

```
dependencies:
  - smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1
  - OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.3.0
compiler:
  solc:
    remappings:
      - '@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@0.2.1'
      - '@openzeppelin=OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.3.0'
networks:
  mainnet-fork:
    eth_usd_price_feed: '0xaEA2808407B7319A31A383B6F8B60f04BCa23cE2'
```

I also tried to change the compiler in lottery.sol file with

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
```

Now I get a different error.
Completely lost here :(

**terminal:**

```
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Brownie v1.17.2 - Python development framework for Ethereum

Compiling contracts...
  Solc version: 0.8.11
  Optimizer: Enabled  Runs: 200
  EVM Version: Istanbul
CompilerError: solc returned the following errors:

ParserError: Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.8.11+commit.d7f03943.Windows.msvc) - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version
 --> C:/Users/rosne/.brownie/packages/smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@0.2.1/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol:2:1:
  |
2 | pragma solidity ^0.6.0;
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

PS D:\Python projects\Solidity dev\demo\smartcontract-lottery>
```

I am very new to programing in solidity and this is the first course I am following, I don't want to give up so easily, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I also noticed that in the brownie-config.yaml file :smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1 was written differently in dependencies and remappings. However, after making both of them the same it still has the same errors. I am trying several things to try and see if I can match the versions somehow. I think I cannot proceed ahead if the code doesn't compile right?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the issue, it was because the function name should be fullfillRandomness instead of FullfillRandomness.
So much problem because of a capital F.

```
function FulfillRandomness(bytes32 _requestId, uint256 _randomness)
        internal
        override
```

Answer (score 7):

The solution to the error is

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.6.0 <0.9.0;
```

Use this instead, hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

replace with these two statements:

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

solves the problem

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue. i had this compiler setting:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;
```

Since we are importing from `openzeppelin`, I visied github repo and saw that it uses `pragma solidity ^0.8.0;`

So changed my setting to

```
 pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.8.0;
```

After compilation I searched for ">=0.6.0 <0.8.0" and got those files. They all from `openzeppelin`

[image]

I did not add solc version to the brownie-yaml file

Comment: I managed to find the issue, it was because the function name should be fullfillRandomness instead of FullfillRandomness.
So much problem because of a capital F. 

function FulfillRandomness(bytes32 _requestId, uint256 _randomness)
        internal
        override

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. For me, it was never resolved by changing the `pragma` within any `.sol` file, and it was never solved by changing the global compiler version within "Visual Studio Code". What did solve the issue was manually setting the compiler version within the `brownie-config.yaml` file. So within the config file there was the below code...

```
compiler:
 solc:
  version: '0.8.4'
```